# Interbase - combining queries

Tags: interbase

I have a table with to columns: `Question` and `Answer`. I want a query that results in one column containing interchangeably the `Question` and it's respective `Answer`.

Exemplifying:

Table "Question_Answer"

```
   Q1, A1
   Q2, A2
   Q3, A3
   Q4, A4
```

Query output, column name "Question_Answer_Result"

```
   Q1
   A1
   Q2
   A2
   Q3
   A3
   Q4
   A4
```

I tried the following command:

```
select "Question_Answer_Result"
from (select "Question_Answer"."Question"
      from   "Question_Answer"
      union all
      select "Question_Answer"."Answer"
      from   "Question_Answer"
     )
```

but I receive a message "Unexpected end of command".

What would be the right SQL command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you selecting from the subquery? The select is looking for column "Question_Answer_Result" from the subquery result; no such column exists. The only column is "Question".

Comment: I have edited the question and I hope now is clear what is my goal.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a column reference in the initial select. As alluded to in my first response, the column 'question' is the result of union subquery. You need to select that column by name (or * will suffice) and then rename it.

select question 'question_answer'
from (
     select question from question_answer
    union all
    select answer from question_answer
         )

EDIT: this is SQLite to get your exact output

```sql
select question 'question_answer'
from (
    select question from question_answer
    union all
    select answer from question_answer
) x
order by substr(question,length(question-1),1),substr(question,1) desc
```

note, the order of output will not be as you illustrated.

Comment: Thanks. I am really not sure what should be the correct SQL command to get the output as pictured in the question. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.